# In terraria mobile, how do you make the ankh Shield?

Tags: terraria-mobile

I know it's one of the best accessories in the game. But how do I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be crafted at a Tinkerer's Workshop out of an Obsidian Shield and an Ankh Charm.

- The Goblin Tinkerer NPC (who can be rescued from underground after defeating a goblin army) sells the Tinkerer's Workshop crafting station for 10 gold.
- The Obsidian Shield is crafted out of a Cobalt Shield (gold chests in the Dungeon) and an Obsidian Skull (20 obsidian at a furnace) at a Tinkerer's Workshop.
- The Ankh Charm is built out of [a bunch of stuff](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Ankh_Charm) at the Tinkerer's Workshop. See the below diagram from [the wiki](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide:Ankh_Shield).

[image]

Terraria Mobile is built on v1.2.1.2 of Terraria (compared to v1.3 on PC). The Ankh Shield was added in v1.2, so making it is the same as on PC.